# Socket IO not emitting events from phone

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a website where I am using socket.io(0.9.16) with node.js(v0.10.22) to manage realtime notifications. Now, this works fine on PC but when I try the same thing from my phone, it fails to emit events. 
For example, if a comment is added to a post, it is broadcasted to all the connected clients. When I add a comment to a post from my phone, it doesn't emit it to the same page open on my PC.

Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which browser are you testing? All browsers supported by `socket.io` here: http://socket.io/#browser-support

Comment: It's NokiaBrowser/8.3.2.21.

Comment: I have same issue in my chat app.

Answer (score 0):

Change the IP address in your client side page.
In my case I had

```
//client side 
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
...
```

I have just changed it to

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.17:8080');
```

Comment: will surely try that sometime. I was working on it last year but now busy with other things. Anyways, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: i was lucky because i only had 2 files in my new project. I think I would not be able to see it in a big project

Comment: and why would you say that?

Comment: because it is easy to detect this error of  when you only have 2 files. So no much code to check

Comment: Oh alright. I thought it just works for small projects.

Comment: Does solution from above with changing IP works?